# How to find the active number of open database connections in H2/MySQL

Tags: mysql, h2

How to find the active number of open database connections in H2/MySQL. We need this information to identify if there are any connection leaks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For H2, use:

```
select * from information_schema.sessions;
```

For MySQL, use:

```
show full processlist;
```

or

```
select * from information_schema.processlist;
```

If you are just interested in the session count, use `select count(*)` instead of `select *`

Comment: select * from information_schema.sessions;
ID   USER_NAME   SESSION_START   STATEMENT   STATEMENT_START  
2 USER1 2011-05-27 09:09:44.98 null 2011-05-27 09:09:48.139
3 USER1 2011-05-27 10:56:32.769 select * from information_schema.sessions 2011-05-27 10:56:34.316

Comment: I get the above information when I run the above SQL statement, but don't get information on the count of connections. Am I missing something

Comment: `select count(*) from information_schema.sessions;`
`select count(*) from information_schema.processlist;`