# Debugging max connection pool reached

Tags: c#, mysql, connection-pooling

Our app is getting a max connection pool reached on pick times when we run large db actions.

I want to debug this situation, My idea is to check how many connections are open every couple of minuets and if i reach a trash-hold to print all the opened queries in the db.

Is that a good approach? Also, does anyone knows how can i check the how many open connection are there, googling didnt help so far.

I am using MySQL.

TY,
Please tell me if any information is missing

Comment: MAke sure you close each connection after the job is done.Also what do you want to debug?Just increase the max connection in mysql config file and restart it

Comment: All the connections are in a using block.My thinking is that maybe i have problematic queries that takes a lot of time to execute and are filling the connection pool, isn't that an option?

Answer (score 0):

Please verify:
1. Use connection pooling - enabled by default (it may turn off)
2. Do not create a globally accessible instance of MySqlConnection and then manually open and close it

Click **[here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-connection-pooling.html)** for more details.

How to find the active number of open database connections in MySQL:

```
select * from information_schema.processlist;
```

Click **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6137683/how-to-find-the-active-number-of-open-database-connections-in-h2-mysql)** for details:

Comment: but the processlist just shows the queries that are running on the db not the open connections..